# Angular 5 HttpClient GET: SUCCESSFUL if in constructor FAILS when ngOnInit

Tags: angular, devexpress, angular5, angular-services

I'm trying to make a http.get.

Its working successfully when the code is in the constructor however when I move the code into the ngOnInit area it fails.

Is there a way to use the code outside the constructor?

I accept normally I would make a service and have tried in in this PLNKR but its failing
https://embed.plnkr.co/JMTfJWLsz7pHzauhnAoM/

**Working Component Code**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-refrate-member',
  templateUrl: './refrate-member.component.html',
  providers: [FetchDataEditService2],
})

export class RefRateMemberComponent {
  dataSource: any = {};
  editing = {};
  private url: string = 'refratemember';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _MasterService: FetchDataEditService2) {

    const API_URL = 'https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/data/orderItems';

    this.editing = this._MasterService.editObject(this.url);

    var myStore = new CustomStore({
      load: function (loadOptions: any) {

        var params = '?';
        params += 'skip=' + loadOptions.skip || 0;
        params += '&take=' + loadOptions.take || 10;

        var thePageNumber = 'pageNumber=' + ((loadOptions.skip / loadOptions.take) + 1);

        if (loadOptions.sort) {
          params += '&orderby=' + loadOptions.sort[0].selector;
          if (loadOptions.sort[0].desc) {
            params += ' desc';
          }
        }
        return http.get(API_URL + params)
          .toPromise()
          .then((res: any) => {
            return {
              data: res.items,
              totalCount: res.totalCount
            }
          })
          .catch(error => { throw 'Data Loading Error' });
      },
      insert: function (values) {
        return http.post(API_URL, values)
          .toPromise();
      },
      remove: function (key) {
        return http.delete(API_URL + encodeURIComponent(key))
          .toPromise();
      },
      update: function (key, values) {
        return http.put(API_URL + encodeURIComponent(key), values)
          .toPromise();
      }
    });

    this.dataSource = new DataSource({
      store: myStore
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

**FAILING Component Code**

ERROR MESSAGE: core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-refrate-member',
  templateUrl: './refrate-member.component.html',
  providers: [FetchDataEditService2],
})

export class RefRateMemberComponent {
  dataSource: any = {};
  editing = {};
  private url: string = 'refratemember';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _MasterService: FetchDataEditService2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const API_URL = 'https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/data/orderItems';

    this.editing = this._MasterService.editObject(this.url);

    var myStore = new CustomStore({
      load: function (loadOptions: any) {

        var params = '?';
        params += 'skip=' + loadOptions.skip || 0;
        params += '&take=' + loadOptions.take || 10;

        var thePageNumber = 'pageNumber=' + ((loadOptions.skip / loadOptions.take) + 1);

        if (loadOptions.sort) {
          params += '&orderby=' + loadOptions.sort[0].selector;
          if (loadOptions.sort[0].desc) {
            params += ' desc';
          }
        }
        return this.http.get(API_URL + params)
          .toPromise()
          .then((res: any) => {
            return {
              data: res.items,
              totalCount: res.totalCount
            }
          })
          .catch(error => { throw 'Data Loading Error' });
      },
      insert: function (values) {
        return this.http.post(API_URL, values)
          .toPromise();
      },
      remove: function (key) {
        return this.http.delete(API_URL + encodeURIComponent(key))
          .toPromise();
      },
      update: function (key, values) {
        return this.http.put(API_URL + encodeURIComponent(key), values)
          .toPromise();
      }
    });

    this.dataSource = new DataSource({
      store: myStore
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `load`, `insert`, `remove`, and `update` properties passed into your `CustomStore` to use arrow functions (or bind a `this` reference to them) in order to use the `this` reference. Those methods are stand alone and not attached to an object and so there is no `this` reference for them. It is recommended to use the new arrow functions over `this` binding in case the code you pass your method to binds a new `this` to it.

#### Arrow Function

```
var myStore = new CustomStore({
    load: (loadOptions: any) => {
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

#### `this` Binding

```
var myStore = new CustomStore({
    load: function(loadOptions: any) {
        ...
    }.bind(this),
    ...
});
```

Comment: absolutely perfect